# Como iterar un dataframe segun los indices de una serie en Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Me gustaría iterar un dataframe y, solo ver, las filas que coincidan con los índices de la siguiente serie:

[image: Serie de pandas:]

He logrado convertir la serie a un Array de indices con .index y .values:

[image: Array de indices]

Gracias a este Array, pude recorrer el dataframe con ayuda de un metodo for pero no me parece el metodo mas eficiente, ¿hay algun otro?:

```
for x in array:
    dataset.loc[x]
```

Comment: ¿Deseas obtener todas las filas de tu serie? o ¿Por qué necesitas iterar? Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega algunas filas de tu `dataset` como texto, no como imagen y el código mínimo necesario para poder reproducir el mismo escenario que tienes.

Comment: ¿no basta con `dataset.loc[estrenar_tit]`?

Comment: @abulafia Me dice KeyError

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Deseo iterar mi dataframe solo por las filas que tengan como indice los elementos del array, por ejemplo:  quiero la fila de mi dataframe 1, 7, 8, 121139 etc (los valores del array).  


La variable "estrenar_tit" surge ya que, para todas las filas de mi dataframe y para una columna en especifico, hice una expresion regular buscando la palabra "estrenar". Entonces, estos indices de "estrenar_tit" son los que contienen la palabra buscada. Ahora, me gustaría agregar una nueva columna que indique que filas estan a estrenar y cuales no.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Si no es molestia, podria hablarte al privado para mejorar mi pregunta? Soy nuevo en StackOverflow y no se me da bien el hecho de formatear las preguntas

Comment: Perdon, quise decir `dataset.loc[estrenar_tit.index]`

Comment: @abulafia Si, exactamente eso quería muchas gracias!. Hay manera de destacar tu comentario o algo asi?

Comment: Puedes puntuar el comentario, para que sea un poco más visible. O puedo escribir una respuesta para que la marques como aceptada, aunque no creo yo que una respuesta que básicamente es una línea...

Answer (score 0):

Este problema es bastante frecuente. Considera el siguiente DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["columna1"] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
df["columna2"] = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
df.index = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]
df
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si yo deseo reducir mi dataframe original a un conjunto de filas específicas, lo que puedo hacer es lo siguiente

```
#Uso una lista con los valores de los índices que deseo
index_que_quiero = [0,4,7,9] 
#accedo a los valores del dataframe usando la función iloc
df.iloc[index_que_quiero]
```

Lo cual mostrará lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que tienes un dataset con varias columnas y en alguna columna tienes números que pudieran coincidir con cualquier indice de la serie *estrenar_tit*.

```py
dataset = pd.DataFrame()
dataset["tit a estrenar"] = [50, 56, 22, 37, 121217, 39, 138]
dataset["pais"] = ['Venezuela', 'Colombia', 'Perú', 'México', 'Brazil', 'Argentina', 'España']
dataset
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asumimos la serie *estrenar_tit* como:

```py
estrenar_tit = pd.Series(['obj1', 'obj2', 'obj3'],
                         index=[22, 39, 121217],
                         name='title')
estrenar_ti
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ver todas las filas del dataset donde la columna "tit a estrenar" coincida con los indices de la serie *estrenar_tit* lo puedes hacer con el siguiente código:

```py
dataset.loc[dataset["tit a estrenar"].isin(estrenar_tit.index)]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]